# How to create a trigger on insert in postgresql to delete records that have same column values as the new records inserted

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers, sql-insert, sql-delete

I have a database in postgresql (v9.3) and I always add records in a batch process (via a ogr2ogr function).  The batch consists of records that have the same postal code, which is stored in a table "location", column "postal_code" (ex:  location.postal_code = "90210").  I want to create a trigger that, each time a batch is inserted into the db, first checks to see if "old" records having the same postal code exists.  If they exist, I want to delete them.  If they do not exist, then the insert statement procedes directly.

I thought of using a trigger with a "before insert" and "for each statement", but the "for each statement" prevents me from using "old" and "new" keywords.  Also, I read that you cannot use a delete function on a table with a trigger having a "before insert" on that same table.  Any ideas of how to do this?

Note: All records that have the same postal code, from a previous batch insert process, should be deleted. Ex: I inserted batch #1 with postal code "90210" on 2014/01/01 and now I have a batch #2 with the same postal code, to insert on 2014/01/31. All records from batch #1 should be deleted and all records from batch #2 should be inserted into the db.  Batch #2 can have more records than batch #1 or less records, which is why I believe I need to delete all records of batch #1 before inserting batch #2.

Comment: You can delete rows in a `before insert` trigger on a table. Also, you need `for each row` indeed, as you need to check the postal code for each insert.

Comment: What should happen if there are already records with the same `postal_code` present? They should be deleted and the new records to be inserted, or the new insert should fail and keep the old records intact?

Comment: All records that have the same postal code,from a previous batch insert process, should be deleted.  Ex:  I inserted batch #1 with postal code "90210" on 2014/01/01 and now I have a batch #2 with the same postal code, to insert on 2014/01/31.  All records from batch #1 should be deleted and all records from batch #2 should be inserted into the db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION delete_duplicate_postal_code() RETURNS "trigger" AS $$
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM batch WHERE postal_code = NEW.postal_code 
      AND (now() - batch.import_timestamp > INTERVAL '5 minutes');
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;

CREATE TRIGGER
  delete_duplicate_postal_code
BEFORE INSERT ON
  batch
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
  delete_duplicate_postal_code();
```

Comment: Your solution works well except that it deletes all rows of my batch#2 insert, except the last one!  ex: batch#1 inserted with postal code '90210' on 2014-01-01 and I then want to insert a batch#2 having the same postal code on 2014-02-02. Executing the "for each row" means that after batch#2 row#1 is inserted, the trigger launches and deletes this row before inserting batch#2 row#2... I have edited your code to add a 2nd condition in the "where" clause that checks the time difference between "now" and the time where the row was inserted (I have this information in my DB).

Comment: You can rely on the transaction ID as well - `txid_current()`, in case these inserts are executed as one transaction. Or define some other criteria uniting these `5 minutes` inserts.

Answer (score 1):

This is also known as an "upsert" (short for "update" or "insert"). An UPSERT(stuff) command is actually being worked on in Postgres right now, so eventually this sort of trigger will be a pessimization, but for now:

```
CREATE upsert() RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
  IF OLD.postal_code = NEW.postal_code
    THEN NEW.some_info = OLD.some_info;
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;
```

This is pretty close, but I haven't had to write one in a while so I might be off the mark a bit.

This is an immensely useful resource: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/triggers.html

Postgres is one of the few open source projects with documentation that vastly surpasses that of most commercial products. If you haven't read them *read them*. You won't only learn about Postgres, you'll learn a different way of thinking which will probably change the fundamental way you think about your data (and inadvertently obviate the need for most triggers such as this).